Setup dev enviroment locally fails on cabal test homework
Hi i setup the dev environment according to the youtube video, "cabal update" worked,  but the second command does not work for me:
root@c26be85e2bf4:/workspace/code/Week02# cabal test homework
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: The test command can only run test suites as a whole, not files or
modules within them, but the target 'Homework' refers to the module Homework
in the library week08.

root@c26be85e2bf4:/workspace/code/Week02#

i used https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program at latest commit b55a7d2409cbf09a04ab471796f410083129acb6

Running cabal test without a target should work. If you want to specify the target, you can check all of them in the Week0X.cabal file.  For example, for week 2, you'll see that there's a test-suite week02-homework target in the Week02.cabal file, so cabal test week02-homework should run those tests specifically.

I am running into the same issue. Did you ever get this resolved on your end?
